# Javascript Scrolling Banner Error

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a website that needs to have a scrolling banner of manufacturer logos.  The problem is that the scrolling action is missing.  Looking at the element in Chrome give me this error: "http://forallgadgets.co.uk/:871 Uncaught ReferenceError: marqueeInit is not defined"  Any thoughts on what might be causing this?  Thanks, Grant.

Header:
    
    /* Text and/or Image Crawler Script v1.5 (c)2009-2011 John Davenport Scheuer
       as first seen in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/
       username: jscheuer1 - This Notice Must Remain for Legal Use
       updated: 4/2011 for random order option, more (see below)
    */

Body:

```
<a href="index.php?route=product/manufacturer&manufacturer_id=52">
<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/manuf_01.jpeg"   width="90" height="30"  
alt="" style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:20px;" /></a>

<a href="index.php?route=product/manufacturer&manufacturer_id=32">
<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/manuf_02.gif"   width="90" height="30"  
alt="" style="margin-left:2px; margin-top:20px;" /></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: 'mycrawler2',
    style: {
        'padding': '0px',
            'width': '690px',
        'height': '71px',
        'margin-left': '10px',
        'margin-right': '10px'
    },
    inc: 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
    mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    moveatleast: 2,
    neutral: 150,
    savedirection: true
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The script; http://www.forallgadgets.com/catalog/view/javascript/crawler.js

Returns a `302; The document has moved <a href="http://www.forallgadgets.co.uk">here</a>` response rather than valid content.

Comment: Brilliant, the error showed up when we changed the address from .com to .co.uk.  Thanks!